# Написать запрос SQL, основываясь на данных из таблиц в excel

Tags: sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Следующая задача: есть файл с экспортированными данными из БД, нужно написать запросы. Как это лучше всего сделать? Есть ли среда куда можно залить таблицы и там написать? Или как-то в экселе можно писать запросы? Файл по ссылке: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fzCFBfuHj4Pnj_u2z3FCFheGnVUlGJ7vRRivQBZ-Vgk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: *Файл по ссылке* Файл, который в любой момент испарится? да кому оно надо? *Есть ли среда куда можно залить таблицы и там написать?* Есть, и немало. Называется online fiddle. Например, https://dbfiddle.uk/ ...

Comment: @Akina спасибо за ссылку, а там есть возможность залить данные с эксель?

Comment: Нет, там пишут SQL-запросы, корректные для выбранной СУБД и версии. Впрочем, преобразовать Excel-таблицу в набор INSERT INTO .. VALUES - несложно.

Comment: @Akina а как преобразовать Excel-таблицу в набор INSERT INTO .. VALUES все данные разом? по одному значению - это глупо делать. Это возможно сделать без VBA?

Comment: Есть функция `СЦЕПИТЬ()`. Вот и соединяйте с соответствующими кавычками и запятыми.